# Minify JS Files Automatically on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is there any way to automatically or using a site tool to minify JavaScript files in a repository that you control on GitHub?

I have forks of projects started by others and I'd like to streamline the process of changing non-minified files and having the minified files changed as a result.

Comment: Minified files are usually considered binaries, not source. *Shudders*

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that it is smart to keep in repository minified version of file.

Repository should contain non minified version.

I assume that you are making web-site, and i can suggest using some sort of tool for minimization of files like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

When you deploy changes to your web site, you can run script, which will minify the file.

Or you can minify files with Grunt before commit.